# Access database from android phone through android app

Tags: android, database, android-studio, database-connection, wamp

i am currently developping an application for my third year project, it's an android app (i used android studio) that will access a database that i created on my wamp server, the connection works perfectly from the application when i debug it on my android phone( i used in my code the "HttpURLConnection" with the url being my pc ip adress that i got from (cmd/ipconfig) ) .
The problem is that once i disconnect my phone from my pc and try to run the application from the phone, the connection with the database won't work, and also if i connect my pc to another modem, my pc ip changes, which is pretty much normal, but i don't think supposed to change the ip everytime the modem i connect to change ( although i'm not really sure, server connexions are clearly not something i'm an expert at ) , so i tried to use the ip of my pc on the internet that i got from "ipaddress.com" but it won't work, not even if i debug the application directly from android studio,
i don't have much time left to present the application , so i need a quick answer, thank you in advance 
P.S : i guess i gotta mention that i need to acces the database to read AND write on it from the phone since it's an app that permits login/registration and will get the data that the user will enter and store it in the database .

Comment: use realm for accessing db

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect the Phone and Mobile in same network.

your connection Url would be Like this 192.10.20.2 which is your ip or computer. as your get it form cmd using ipconfig command.

but whenever your networks changes your have to decompile to change the ip. or provide ip via textview.

take a Editview to take ip. and the concat it to your url. this will work. as it worked for me.

Comment: i didn't understand what you meant by taking a textview to take the ip, and how do i exactly connect the phone and pc to the same network, they actually both are connected to the same modem through the WIFI

Comment: whenEver Ip changes you have to change the url right? as database is in Ur PC you have to give the actual ip of PC. whenever it changes

Comment: yes exactly, i thought that mayeb there could be a way to use a static ip so i won't have to change it everytime, and for the phone acces to the db, even if they're onnected to the same modem, the phone still won't access the db if it's disconnected from the pc, i read somewhere that i acually had to change the http.conf file of apache , in this file i have the line " ServerName localhost:80" , maybe the problem is coming from the "localhost" so i changed it to my pc ip adress but it didn't work

Comment: that is why! i told to take an Edittext. which will get it current ip of your PC. i mean now your are changing the IP and again building the apk. but if you take edittext and insert your ip there. then you dont have to rebuilt your code again again.

Comment: just take the value and concate it to Your URL as etText.getText().toString()+"/"+insert.php

Comment: so everytime the ip changes i'll have to enter it through an edittext, that will solve the problem of  having to recompile everytime, but whaa i was looking for is a way to use the same ip whatever the network is ( i don't understand why the ip adress of my device on the unternet won't work ) or if changing it, make it automatical through programmation and most of all invisible to the eye of the user, i don't know if i'm really clear, i thought of using something like WIFIManager but it didn't work, maybe i did something wrong

Comment: then i belive you have to google how to fix the ip address of a computer. i have not tested it, but this might help you https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/19249/how-to-assign-a-static-ip-address-in-xp-vista-or-windows-7/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know wheter understanded, when you disconnect your phone from your pc, the app dead? or simplely it don't connect with db. Regard router, you need an account in "no-ip" and configure forguard's router on port 80 to redirect your computer's static IP. i need more details and information to help you. Regards

Comment: when i disconnect the phone, the app still works, but it won't connect to the db , i actually catch the exception ( java.lang.NullPointerException Attempt to invoke virtual method boolean java.lang.String.equals on a null object reference ) , and that comes from the fact that in the php code " $mysql_qry = "select * from donateur where email like '$email'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn , $mysql_qry); " $result returns false which means that the connection didn"t work, for the router, if you could give me more details about the (no-ip)  account it would be great, thank you

Comment: Okey, i need that you post the script php, your java code, log trace. regard to router, i need know if you're working on LAN or if you connect externaly to server? because NO-IP provides a DNS to reference your host. is for monitoring wheter if your public ip change or not change

Answer (score 0):

```
     i'm working on an external server 
The php code (for the connection to the db)
  <?php
$db_name="pfe";
$mysql_username="root";
$mysql_password="";
$server_name="localhost";
$conn = mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_username,$mysql_password,$db_name);
?>
then i got another php file which handles the login part
 <?php
require "connexion.php";
$user_email =$_POST["user-email"];
$user_pass =$_POST["password"];
$mysql_qry = "select id from donateur where email like '$user_email' and                 
password like '$user_pass'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn , $mysql_qry);
if(($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))!=null){
$a = array('myarray' => array("donateur", $row["id"]));
echo json_encode($a);}
else {
    $mysql_qry2 = "select id, username from association where email like     
'$user_email' and password like '$user_pass'";
$result2 = mysqli_query($conn , $mysql_qry2);
if(($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2))!=null) { $a = array('myarray' => 
array("association", $row["id"]));
echo json_encode($a);
}
 else { echo "rien";}}
$conn->close();

    the java code : 

package applis.pfe;
import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;

import android.content.CursorLoader;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import static android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS;


public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements             
LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

/**
 * Id to identity READ_CONTACTS permission request.
 */
private static final int REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 0;

DonateurDAO donateurdao= new DonateurDAO(this);
AssociationDAO associationdao=new AssociationDAO(this);
/**
 * Keep track of the login task to ensure we can cancel it if requested.
 */
String ip="http://105.101.179.155/";
private UserLoginTask mAuthTask = null;

// UI references.
private AutoCompleteTextView mEmailView;
private EditText mPasswordView;
private View mProgressView;
private View mLoginFormView;
public static String qui;
public static int id;
public static String username;
SessionManager session;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    ///////////////////// POUR AFFICHER LE MESSAGE DIINSCRIPTION REUSSIE /////////////////////////////////////
if(getIntent().getStringExtra("inscription")!=null &&         
getIntent().getStringExtra("inscription").equals("oui"))
{ AlertDialog a= new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this).create();
    a.setTitle("Inscription réussie !");
    a.setMessage("Votre inscription a été validé, veuillez vous connecter     
pour pouvoir continuer");
    a.show();}
    session = new SessionManager(this);
    // Set up the login form.
    mEmailView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
  //  populateAutoComplete();
    mPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    mPasswordView.setOnEditorActionListener(new 
 TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int id, KeyEvent         
keyEvent) {
                if (id == R.id.login || id == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
                    attemptLogin();
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    Button mEmailSignInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.email_sign_in_button);
    mEmailSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {attemptLogin();

        }
    });

    mLoginFormView = findViewById(R.id.login_form);
    mProgressView = findViewById(R.id.login_progress);

ImageButton btn;
    btn =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.InscriptionDonateurButton);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {Intent in= new     
Intent(LoginActivity.this,InscriptionDonateurActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });

   ImageButton btn1;
  btn1 =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.InscriptionAssociationButton);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {Intent in= new     
Intent(LoginActivity.this,InscriptionAssociationActivity.class);
        startActivity(in);
        }
    });
}


    private void attemptLogin() {
        if (mAuthTask != null) {
            return;
        }

        // Reset errors.
        mEmailView.setError(null);
        mPasswordView.setError(null);

    // Store values at the time of the login attempt.
    String email = mEmailView.getText().toString();
    String password = mPasswordView.getText().toString();

    boolean cancel = false;
    View focusView = null;

    // Check for a valid password, if the user entered one.
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(password) && !isPasswordValid(password)) {
        mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_password));
        focusView = mPasswordView;
        cancel = true;
    }

    // Check for a valid email address.
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
        mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
        focusView = mEmailView;
        cancel = true;
    } else if (!isEmailValid(email)) {
        mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_email));
        focusView = mEmailView;
        cancel = true;
    }

    if (cancel) {
        // There was an error; don't attempt login and focus the first
        // form field with an error.
        focusView.requestFocus();
    } else {
        // Show a progress spinner, and kick off a background task to
        // perform the user login attempt.
        showProgress(true);
        mAuthTask = new UserLoginTask(email, password);
        mAuthTask.execute((Void) null);
    }
}

private boolean isEmailValid(String email) {
    //TODO: Replace this with your own logic
   return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();

}

private boolean isPasswordValid(String password) {
    //TODO: Replace this with your own logic
    return password.length() > 4;
}

/**
 * Shows the progress UI and hides the login form.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
private void showProgress(final boolean show) {
    // On Honeycomb MR2 we have the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs, which allow
    // for very easy animations. If available, use these APIs to fade-in
    // the progress spinner.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
        int shortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);

        mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        mLoginFormView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime).alpha(
                show ? 0 : 1).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        mProgressView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime).alpha(
                show ? 1 : 0).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            }
        });
    } else {
        // The ViewPropertyAnimator APIs are not available, so simply show
        // and hide the relevant UI components.
        mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
    return new CursorLoader(this,
            // Retrieve data rows for the device user's 'profile' contact.
            Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.CONTENT_DIRECTORY), ProfileQuery.PROJECTION,

            // Select only email addresses.
            ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE +
                    " = ?", new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email
            .CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE},

            // Show primary email addresses first. Note that there won't be
            // a primary email address if the user hasn't specified one.
            ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.IS_PRIMARY + " DESC");
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor) {
    List<String> emails = new ArrayList<>();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        emails.add(cursor.getString(ProfileQuery.ADDRESS));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }

    addEmailsToAutoComplete(emails);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader) {

}

private void addEmailsToAutoComplete(List<String> emailAddressCollection) {
    //Create adapter to tell the AutoCompleteTextView what to show in its dropdown list.
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<>(LoginActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, emailAddressCollection);

    mEmailView.setAdapter(adapter);
}


private interface ProfileQuery {
    String[] PROJECTION = {
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.IS_PRIMARY,
    };

    int ADDRESS = 0;
    int IS_PRIMARY = 1;
}

/**
 * Represents an asynchronous login/registration task used to authenticate
 * the user.
 */
public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    private final String mEmail;
    private final String mPassword;

    UserLoginTask(String email, String password) {
        mEmail = email;
        mPassword = password;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.
String login_url= ip.concat("login.php");
        try {
            URL url= new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream= httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter= new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));
            String Post_data= URLEncoder.encode("user-email","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(mEmail,"UTF-8")+"&"
                    +URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(mPassword,"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(Post_data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream=httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            qui=null;
            id=0;
            BufferedReader bufferedReader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
            String  resultat="";
           String ligne="";
            while((ligne=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
            resultat += ligne;
if (resultat.equals("rien")) return  resultat; else {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(resultat);
           JSONArray json_data = jsonObject.getJSONArray("myarray");
            qui=json_data.getString(0);
            id=json_data.getInt(1);
               username= json_data.getString(2);}
          /*  for(int i=0;i<json_data.length();i++)
            {
                k++;
                qui= json_data.getString(1);
                id= json_data.getInt(2);
                //r.add(json_data.getString("categorie"));

            }*/

            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return resultat;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();return e.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();return e.toString();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); return  e.toString();
        }
    }
      /*  for (String credential : DUMMY_CREDENTIALS) {
            String[] pieces = credential.split(":");
            if (pieces[0].equals(mEmail)) {
                // Account exists, return true if the password matches.
                return pieces[1].equals(mPassword);
            }
        }*/

        // TODO: register the new account here.



    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String resultat) {
        mAuthTask = null;
        showProgress(false);
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        Intent i;
        AlertDialog a;

        if (resultat.equals("rien")){i= new Intent(LoginActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
            a= new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this).create();
            a.setTitle("Erreur");
            a.setMessage(" Email et/ou mot de passe erroné(s)");
            a.show();} else {

            try {
                session.createLoginSession(mEmail,username,qui,id);
                session.checkLogin();
                if (qui.equals("donateur")) {

                    i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Suite_Inscription_Donateur.class);
                    i.putExtra("id", id);
                    startActivity(i);
                } else if (qui.equals("association")) {

                    session.createLoginSession(mEmail,username,qui,id);
                    i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Suite_Inscription_Association.class);
                    i.putExtra("id", id);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                a= new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this).create();
                a.setTitle("Erreur");
                a.setMessage("Erreur :".concat(e.toString()));
                a.show();
            }
        }


    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        mAuthTask = null;
        showProgress(false);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: i think that you're receiving null because your script not send nothing. try:

 <?php
$db_name="pfe";
$mysql_username="root";
$mysql_password="";
$server_name="localhost";
$conn=mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_username,$mysql_password,$db_name);

if($conn){
     echo "connected"
}else{
     echo "not connected"
}
?>

Comment: no i actually forgot to add the php script that handles the login, it's that one that uses the connection.php file and returns something, and this code does return me something when i debug th app, but it doesn't when i launch the app on a disconnected phone, do i have to put the db online throgh a web hosting for it to work ?